# How to make images upload faster in an Android app?

Tags: android, upload

I am developing an Android app which is like OLX, allowing the user to add​ ads and course select images from gallery to upload onto my server. But uploading large images​ takes​ a long time.

How can I fix this issue?

I am using **Volley library** for uploading the images. Are there any better libraries?

Comment: try using Retrofit to upload image

Comment: Are you converting image to base64?

Comment: Yes  Azhar osws i am using base64 ,i convert the bitmap first to string and then post to the remote server which sometimes give me out of memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*use this*

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().client(okHttpClient).baseUrl(domain)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
   Service service = retrofit.create(Service.class);

   RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);

   final MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestBody);
   final RequestBody filename = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), file.getName());

   Call<ServerResponse> upload = service.uploadFile(fileToUpload, filename);

   upload.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, final Response<ServerResponse> response) {
            final ServerResponse serverResponse = response.body();
            if (serverResponse.getSuccess()) {
                //Handle Response
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            if(t instanceof SocketTimeoutException){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable To Upload\nError: Socket Time out. Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

*Service Interface*

```
public interface Service {
@Multipart
@POST("path/upload.php")
Call<ServerResponse> uploadFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Part("file") RequestBody name);
```

}

Comment: Adnan Momin, i think you are right but it seems more complicated isn't it?

Comment: @aym1781969 learn using https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLvhXArWo3eVxIMKJE5_zU1zb-ZHQISQT_ this link. It's easy

Answer (score 2):

Your question is quite broad, but here are some ideas:

- **Resize your images to a smaller size:** the user might upload 12-16 megapixel images, but 1920x1080 is usually more than enough, which is only ~2 megapixels, a lot smaller.
- **Use a different format with lossy compression:** a 75% quality JPEG picture is almost indistinguishable from a 100%, while it can be 2 or 3 times smaller in size.
- **Increase buffer size for the request**: Higher buffer sizes lead to less packets, which means faster uploads. Although if the user has a very bad connection (packet loss very high), smaller packets can be sometimes faster.

You will see high performance gains with the first two points, you might only see a bit of improvement with the last point if you are very far from the server geographically.

Comment: How can you set the buffer size when using HttpURLConnection?